# Page Feature Image Problems in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, dynamic

I am taking a course and I coded a custom website along with the instructor, but I can't figure out why my header image is shorter on the Resources page(https://topcdltraining.com/resources/) and Contact page(https://topcdltraining.com/contact/) when it should be the same height as the header image on the Blog page(https://topcdltraining.com/blog/). Can someone please help me see where I screwed this up? I have the same exact html code for all three pages in regards to the feature image and H1 title (I even copied and pasted the same code on all three pages again and changed the title just to be sure). I added the HTML, CSS and PHP code for the static Resources page as well as the page-resources.php page below (please ignore the comments I added to the PHP code - I am a noob at this so I added the comments to help me remember how to do all this later on).

````
```
<section class="feature-image feature-image-default-alt" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
            <h1 class="page-title">Blog</h1>
        </section><!-- feature-image -->

============================= CSS ======================================

.feature-image {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.feature-image-default {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/stuff-feature.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.feature-image-default-alt {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/hipster-stuff.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.feature-image h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

============================== PHP ==========================================

<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // add php code to check for featured image ?>

        <!-- add php to allow featured image to be shown by url -->
        <section class="feature-image" style="background:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
            <!-- add php code to make title dynamic -->
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </section><!-- feature-image -->

        <?php } else { // add php code for fallback image if there is no featured image ?>
        <section class="feature-image feature-image-default" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
            <!-- add php code to make title dynamic -->
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </section><!-- feature-image -->

        <?php } ?>
````

============== INSTRUCTOR'S PHP CODE ======================

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Resources Page */ 

get_header();

$thumbnail_url  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
?>

    <!-- FEATURE IMAGE
    ================================================== -->
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>

    <section class="feature-image" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } else { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-default" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } ?>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="primary">

            <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">

                <section class="main-content">

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop ?>

                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'resource', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="resource-row clearfix">

                        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php
                            $resource_image = get_field('resource_image');
                            $resource_url   = get_field('resource_url');
                            $button_text    = get_field('button_text'); 
                        ?>

                        <div class="resource">

                            <img src="<?php echo $resource_image[url]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $resource_image[alt]; ?>">


                            <h3><a href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <?php if( !empty($button_text) ) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $button_text; ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- resource -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </div><!-- resource-row -->

                </section><!-- main-content -->

            </div><!-- content -->

        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?
```

>

````
```
````

Comment: Can't find the line where you set the value for the $thumbnail_url you are using inside of the if clause. Did you forget to get the url and save it to the variable, or is there some code missing in your question?

Comment: II added the instructor's PHP code for the resources page because I'm not sure how to answer your last question.

Answer (score 0):

The body element of you blog page has the classes:

```
<body class="blog hfeed">
```

The body element of your other two pages have also the "page" class:

```
<body class="... page ...">
```

In your css stylesheet you have the follwing:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'proxima-nova', 'Raleway', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/tile.jpg') top left repeat;
}
```

The important line is the "margin-top: 50px;" which defines the space above your body, so that the fixed topbar does not overlay the header.

You also have this in your css:

```
.post, .page {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

This overwrites the margin-top for all elements with the class of "page" or "post" and sets it to "0px".

You have two ways to solve this. Add an !important to your margin-top so it will not be overwritten:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

Or you can change the values for the .post and .page:

```
.post, .page {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```